# How can I recover a deleted disk image file that was made using dd?

Tags: data-recovery, dd, xfs

I accidentally deleted a disk image that I created using dd. The drive that the disk image file was on has an XFS file system. I was looking to use photorec but it does not appear to have the ability to find a disk image file created using `dd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before trying to recover a deleted file, it's most important to not modify the file system anymore, to avoid accidentially overwriting the file you want to undelete. Therefore, shut down the computer, and make a copy (e.g. using dd) of the affected partition. Then, boot from another partition (or a USB stick, CD, whatever you have) and proceed from there.

You can try using [xfs_undelete](https://github.com/ianka/xfs_undelete) to recover your file.